# Вывод графических символов в формате utf-8

Tags: php

Суть проблемы следующая, у нас есть функция, которая просто случайно генерирует строку

```
<?php
function Random_string(){
        $size = rand(0,80);
        $str = "";  
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        $str .= chr(rand(32,127));
    return $str;
 }
?>
```

Но, как сделать так, чтобы можно было генерировать случайную строку графических символов из кодировки utf-8?
  Как я понял, кодировка имеет вид $#****, где * число. И допустим я хочу сгенерировать диапазон от 1000-1500, но я не знаю как сделать, т.к после хештега он игнорит код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути, только UTF-8 cимволы используют не $, а &

Вывод происходит так

```
<p>I will display &#9824;</p> - десятичный формат

<p>I will display &#x2660;</p> - шестнадцатиричный формат
```

И некоторые браузеры могут не поддерживать.

Вот Ваша функция поправленная http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdfb7b96d51240ab12f83cffd397c2156c50bfff